# Restart GUI without rebooting the system

Tags: command-line, window-manager

How can I restart my GUI (X window server) from command line without rebooting the system? Which process(es) do I need to kill and do they automatically restart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need to do is restart LightDM as root, like so:

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

Comment: You should probably mention that you should do this from a TTY (virtual terminal).

Comment: I was guessing from the level of detail of the question that Mr. Wolf knows his way around the terminal. :)

Comment: I wasn't just referring to the "terminal", but oh well. (I said virtual for a reason. I mean the thing you get when you press ctrl+alt+f-key-of-your-choice).

Comment: Oh, I see. And what would the advantage be in this case? How would that work? Curious myself now. :)

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Answer (score 2):

The worst is that noone mentioned that you must use alt+ctrl+F1 to F6 to switch to terminal. Login there as standard user. Restart x with sudo command and then press alt+ctrl+F7 to go back to GUI.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04, I do this executing next command:

```
sudo systemctl restart lightdm
```